# Saving image to SD Card in a Worklight application

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I have created a Worklight application and added to it the Android environment. This application has a button to take a photo using the device camera, and an `img` tag in the HTML which displays the captured photo.

I followed this [PhoneGap Camera API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html).

Now I am trying to store that image into the SD Card but fail doing so. my

EDIT: I changed my code as below:

```
function takeimage() {
// Retrieve image file location from specified source
navigator.camera.getPicture(getImageURI, function(message) {
alert('Image Capture Failed');
}, {
quality : 40,
destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
});
}
function getImageURI(imageURI) {

var gotFileEntry = function(fileEntry) { 
    var img=document.getElementById("thisImage");
    img.style.visiblity="visible";
    img.style.display="block";
    img.src=imageURI;
        alert("got image file entry: " + fileEntry.fullPath); 
        var gotFileSystem = function(fileSystem){ 
            // copy the file 
            fileEntry.moveTo(fileSystem.root, "pic.jpg", null, null); 
       }; 
        // get file system to copy or move image file to 
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFileSystem, fsFail); 
    }; 
    //resolve file system for image  
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, gotFileEntry, fsFail); 
}
//file system fail 
function fsFail(error) { 
    alert("failed with error code: " + error.code); 
}
```

Everything working fine(capturing image and image available in app cache folder) except `moveTo` method.
`fileEntry.moveTo(fileSystem.root, "pic.jpg", null, null);` 
I put `fileSystem.root` in alert and I am getting `Object object`. So the folder location is not available to move that image(And I think its the real problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This, in fact, has got nothing to do with Worklight.

Since you are already using Apache Cordova to access the device's camera to snap a photo, you should also use it to store the image file to the device's SD Card.

Here are a couple of SO questions to point you to the right solution for you:

- [How to move captured image in PhoneGap to a folder in sdcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904158/how-to-move-captured-image-in-phonegap-to-a-folder-in-sdcard)
- [Capturing and storing a picture taken with the Camera into a local database / PhoneGap / Cordova / iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335563/capturing-and-storing-a-picture-taken-with-the-camera-into-a-local-database-ph)

**Note #1:** your link to the PhoneGap Camera API points to v1.0.
Worklight 5.0.6.x uses PhoneGap 2.3.0, so be sure to [use the correct API version](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera).

**Note #2:** make sure you have added permission to write to the SD Card by adding the below line to the android.manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Note #3:** in case #2 above is not enough, try getting the SD Card location like this:

```
File sdDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Comment: Thanks Idan, in second example link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335563/capturing-and-storing-a-picture-taken-with-the-camera-into-a-local-database-ph) I am getting this error in my log

`05-04 00:11:33.521: D/CordovaLog(946): Uncaught TypeError: Wrong type for parameter "uri" of resolveLocalFileSystemURI: Expected String, but got global.`

Comment: Edit your question with the code you've written to handle the image saving.

Comment: Hi Idan, surprise to see you are working on weekend, I edited my post please check the code.I am able to click the picture and it saving on cache but moving image is not working. Thanks

Comment: HI Idan, still itching my hair. I have tried everything but its not working. can you just givea code to move my image from cache to any folder(eg `"file:///mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.camera1.123324323.jpg"` to `"file:///mnt/sdcard"`)

Comment: cause moving is the only problem i am facing.

Comment: IDAN Grrreat. without a single change its working. Image was not showing on AVD gallery(don'tknow why). I Highly appreciate your help. :-)
You are Worklight King.
PS- I checked those Images in DDMS Prospective in Worklight and they were there.

Answer (score 0):

use this option in your takePicture callback

```
{ 
  saveToPhotoAlbum: true
};
```

Also use all other option too as per your requirement. This will save your image to photolibrary.

**saveToPhotoAlbum: Save the image to the photo album on the device after capture. (Boolean)**

It will save your image to sd card without writing any extra code.