# cordova plugin camera select from image gallery wrong type error

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I want to select an image from my image gallery with the cordova camera plugin but always get the same error

```
'Wrong type for parameter "uri" of resolveLocalFileSystemURI: Expected String, but got Null'
```

This is my code and it is similar to what is on the cordova-plugin-camera repo on github but still i get the same error

```
var options = {
      destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
      allowEdit : false,
      //encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      correctOrientation: true
    };

    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {

    })
```

imageData is always null. I have no clue why this error because documentation says this is the right wat.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16361970/1765530

Comment: Try with this options `var options = {
      quality : 75,
      // destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      destinationType : navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      sourceType :navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY;,
      // allowEdit : true,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      targetWidth: 300,
      targetHeight: 300,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    };`